# Override a specific inline style using Firefox browser?

Tags: css, firefox, inline

I need to override an inline style for a specific web page using a practical client-side solution within Firefox. I don't have access to the source code. I used to modify manually the page source code using Firefox development tools.

To be more specific, I access a web page with a form to upload files, but the "submit" button has a visibility set to "hidden". The inline style that I need to override is:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload selected file" style="visibility: hidden">
```

Is there a way to permanently override the "hidden" value of this form submit button WITHIN Firefox browser? There was a time when a specific Firefox extension (I can't recall its name) was able to perform such a thing...

Comment: which website do you need to do this to?

Comment: @IP_ADDRESS It's a private Web application consisting of a form with a file upload field and a submit button.

Comment: could you change it using inspect element or

Comment: [Grease Monkey extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonke/) for Firefox might provide this kind of functionality but I'm not happy with their privacy policy

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
 css:
 input[type=submit] {
 visibility:visible !important;
 }
```

use the !important style to override inline styles

Answer (score 0):

You can apply your CSS using !important, you do not need to change the HTML for your input tag.

http://jsfiddle.net/dqzryyxo/

```
input[type=submit] {
  visibility: visible !important;  

}
```

Comment: This will work on the majority of browser not only in Firefox :-)

Comment: I do not have access to the webpage sourcecode, as mentionned in my question. I need a solution to override this setting WITHIN the Web browser (client-side). Maybe the question is not clear enough, I'll try to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

For those that are interested:
https://ffeathers.wordpress.com/2013/03/10/how-to-override-css-stylesheets-in-firefox/